# Parallel Test Execution using Jenkins

Tags: automated-testing, jenkins

I have some automated tests that I'm running using Jenkins.

I've Jenkins connected to my GitSwarm which pulls the code from my branch and then exectutes it.

I have installed the "Parallel Test Job Execution Plugin" for Jenkins.

In the plugin I have specified the tests to run in 3 batches

[image: screenshot]

Is there anything else I should specify? I didn't think I would have to since I'm connecting to GitSwarm to run the code. The console output seems to state otherwise !

**No record available, so executing everything in one place
[parameterized-trigger] Current build has no parameters.
ERROR: Build aborted. No projects to trigger. Check your configuration!
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: C:\jenkins\jobs\GIT_DVT\workspace\unisphere360\target\surefire-reports\
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: FAILURE**

Any help would be greatly appreciated, it does seem like an easy way to have tests running parallel so hopefully its only a small error.

Thanks,
Colin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a Build Flow plugin to create a Build Flow job.

Within the Build Flow job I was able to specify 3 other Maven Jobs to run parallel.

This meant I had 3 Maven jobs that where pointing to 3 different XML files that contained different test cases.

With the Build Flow job I was also to set these jobs to run parallel with each other, thus achieving 3 test XMLs to run parallel.

Just an answer for anyone looking for something similar.